# Optimizing Redis performance and increasing CPU utilization

Tags: performance, redis

I need some ideas for how to increase Redis performance and CPU utilization for my application.

I have 2 environments, staging and production. Note that both of these are VMs.

Production is a 12-core system, with the below specs:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 1808
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cache size      : 20480 KB
```

Staging is a 4-core system with the below specs:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5690  @ 3.47GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 21
cpu MHz         : 3466.789
cache size      : 12288 KB
```

However, I am getting a much lower Redis benchmark in my production environment:

```
PRODUCTION::[c./redis-benchmark -q -n 100000
PING_INLINE: 30911.90 requests per second
PING_BULK: 31065.55 requests per second
SET: 27247.96 requests per second
GET: 33760.97 requests per second
INCR: 34843.21 requests per second
LPUSH: 33178.50 requests per second
LPOP: 32154.34 requests per second
SADD: 37608.12 requests per second
SPOP: 38491.14 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 35161.74 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 22773.86 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 12312.24 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 9775.17 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 7113.39 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 29708.85 requests per second
```

As compared to staging environment:

```
SIT [cdmxa@cdmapp01d bin]$ ./redis-benchmark -q -n 100000
PING_INLINE: 165016.50 requests per second
PING_BULK: 163132.14 requests per second
SET: 142653.36 requests per second
GET: 157480.31 requests per second
INCR: 161550.89 requests per second
LPUSH: 151515.14 requests per second
LPOP: 153374.23 requests per second
SADD: 163934.42 requests per second
SPOP: 161030.59 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 151057.41 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 65359.48 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 23137.44 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 16714.02 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 12904.89 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 72674.41 requests per second
```

Also noticed that CPU utilization is very low in the production environment:

[mpstat results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXbtR.png)

Is the redis benchmark so low because of just the CPU or could there be other factors contributing to this?

Any suggestions on what I can do to improve performance?

Thanks!

Updates (7th April):
Redis version on both servers are the same.

Comment: Redis is mostly single threaded so the number of cores is irrelevant in this case. What else is different between the staging and production servers?

Comment: adding to the questions: is it the same Redis version ? is it the same config for both servers ?

Comment: @ItamarHaber I see. I was thinking along the lines of making Redis run faster so it is able to handle more clients at a faster speed to maximize CPU utilization (btw 'clients' are on the same server).

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab Yes, same Redis version. May I know what kind of config do you have in mind which could affect performance?